# Richtextbox deselecting text when user uses another control

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox

I have a TabControl with a custom RichTextBox control inside it.  I have some ComboBoxes in a Toolbar (in a toolstripcontainer) that contain lists of font types and sizes.

When the user selects some text in the rtb, and goes to change the font, the selected text deselects automatically when the user clicks on any other control in the form, rendering the font selection boxes useless.

Is there something I'm missing here? Because I expected the text to stay selected.  Any suggestions are helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows Forms?  The selection should persist when focus is lost, so for example setting .SelectionFont should work fine.  Set .HideSelection = false and see if you can observe it becoming deselected.

Comment: The selection should not be lost, but it may be hidden from view.  This is the default setting and is controlled by the `HideSelection` property of the RTB.  Try setting that property to `False`.